# SSRS Sort by Varchar column

Tags: sorting, view, reporting-services, expression, grouping

I have a view that contain a varchar column(Engaged Hour) to indicate a time portion of a event happened. It has following values when ordered(by Engaged Hour column)
0AM,10AM,10PM,11AM,11PM,12AM,1AM,1PM,2AM,2PM

But I want them to order as follows( AM values first and then PM values)
0AM,10AM,11AM,12AM,1AM,10PM,11PM,1PM

Answer (score 0):

=CDate(Fields!EngagedHour.Value) will sort the data accurately

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).